# How to apply a function on each field of a case class

Tags: scala, scalaz

Let's consider a classification problem :

```
object Classify extends App {
  type Tag = String
  type Classifier[A] = A => Set[Tag]

  case class Model(a: Int, b: String, c: String, d: String)

  def aClassifier : Classifier[Int] = _ => Set("A", "a")
  def bClassifier : Classifier[String] = _ => Set("B")
  def cClassifier : Classifier[String] = _ => Set("C")

  def modelClassifier : Classifier[Model] = {
    m => aClassifier(m.a) ++ bClassifier(m.b) ++ cClassifier(m.c)
  }

  println(modelClassifier(Model(1,"b", "c", "d")))
}
```

Is there a smarter way to implement `modelClassifier` using scalaz ?

Comment: How int classifier differs of string classifier in that case?

Answer (score 1):

As an idea, consider this code:

```
 for (i <- 0 until model.productArity) yield {
  val fieldValue = model.productElement(i)
  fieldValue match {
    case x: Int => //use integer classifier
    case s: String => //use string classifier
    case _ => 
  }
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

scalaz library hasn't any macro `case class` introspection by design, but [shapeless](https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless) has

Consider such definitions:

```
import shapeless._
import shapeless.tag._
import shapeless.labelled._

trait Omit
val omit = tag[Omit]

case class Model(a: Int, b: String, c: String, d: String @@ Omit)
```

Let define following [polymorphic function](https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless/wiki/Feature-overview:-shapeless-2.0.0#polymorphic-function-values)

```
object classifiers extends Poly1 {
  implicit def stringClassifier[K <: Symbol](implicit witness: Witness.Aux[K]) =
    at[FieldType[K, String]](value => Set(witness.value.name.toUpperCase))

  implicit def intClassifier[K <: Symbol](implicit witness: Witness.Aux[K]) =
    at[FieldType[K, Int]](value => {
      val name = witness.value.name
      Set(name.toUpperCase, name.toLowerCase)
    })

  implicit def omitClassifier[K, T] =
    at[FieldType[K, T @@ Omit]](_ => Set.empty[String])
}
```

Now your `modelClassifier` could be done as:

```
def modelClassifier: Classifier[Model] = 
  m => LabelledGeneric[Model].to(m).map(classifiers).toList.reduce(_ union _)
```

you can check it via

```
println(modelClassifier(Model(1, "b", "c", omit("d"))))
```

Note that `Type @@ Tag` is subtype of `Type` so `model.d` still could be used as `String` everywhere

Answer (score 0):

How do you intend to distinguish between `bClassifier` and `cClassifier`? By name? By order of declaration? That does not sound very "smart" or reliable. Consider encoding your intent explicitly instead. Something like this, perhaps:

```
case class Classifiable[T](data: T, classifier: Classifier[T])
object Classifiable {
     def Null[T](data: T) = Classifiable(data, _ => Nil)
} 

case class Model(a: Classifiable[Int], b: Classifiable[String], c: Classifiable[String], d: Classifiable[String])

object Model {
   def apply(a: Int, b: String, c: String, d: String) = 
      Model(
         Classifiable(a, aClassifier), 
         Classifiable(b, bClassifier),
         Classifiable(c, cClassifier),
         Classifiable.Null(d)
      )
}

def modelClassifier(m: Model) = m
 .productIterator
 .collect { case x: Classifiable[_] => 
    x.classifier()(x)
 }
 .reduce(_ ++ _)     


 println(modelClassifier(Model(1,"b", "c", "d")))
```